# Does iOS App Appeareance depend on deployment target?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13

I have released an iOS App with iOS 12 deployment target. After updating my XCode the app looks different now in Simulator and on my test device with iOS 13 (Dark mode active, new UISegmented control styles). If I download the app from the App Store it still looks like before.

Why does the Vesion compiled in XCode look different now than it does downloaded from the App Store?
Will the UI differ between iOS 12 and 13 if I release a new app Version?

Comment: Can you describe how exactly your app looks different?

Comment: Yes you will see some cosmetic changes when you use some colors with support the dark mode. Also you will see the old segment control in iOS 12 and updated one if you are running app on iOS 13.

Comment: @matsbauer It uses dark mode now and UISegmentedControl looks different

Answer (score 1):

> Does iOS App Appeareance depend on deployment target?

In general it’s not the *deployment* target that matters, it’s the *build* target.

- If your iOS 12 app, built with Xcode 10, suddenly finds itself running on iOS 13, there is basically no change.
- But if you rebuild your app with Xcode 11, now you are linked against the iOS 13 sdk, and the new iOS 13 look and behavior springs to life. (And you will probably have quite a lot of rewriting to do.)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't described how your app looks different,  but generally when Apple introduces changes they will keep the behaviour based on the SDK that was used to build an app.

This helps ensures backward compatibility and explains why your App Store version (which presumably was built against the iOS 12 SDK) appears like it always has.

Once it start building against the new SDK you get the new appearance/behaviour and you need to implement any required changes.

So, yes, if you submit a new build to the App Store it will look like the Xcode build does on iOS 13 devices.

Answer (score 0):

There will be some cosmetic changes with iOS 13 even if you build your app against iOS 12 SDK.

- If you were using Default UIColor and if that color set will have dark/light support then it will reflect in your app when you switch the appearance.
- For segmented control iOS 13 have a new look. So if you used native control in iOS 12 for development then in iOS 12 you will see the old look while in iOS 13 there will be new look on running the app.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few questions in here:

**Does iOS App Appeareance depend on deployment target?**

The deployment target is what you set in xcode under the project, and is already referred to as the minimum deployment target. This in itself does not change the working of the app

**Why does the version compiled in XCode look different now than it does downloaded from the App Store?**

You kind of answered this one yourself already, it's not so much different from the app store, as it is compiled by a different version of XCode.

**Will the UI differ between iOS 12 and 13 if I release a new app Version?**

In short: Yes.

Some interface elements will look and/or behave differently. Take some extra care testing on both iOS 12 and 13. 
Two things in particular to check out are [dark mode support](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/dark-mode-support-ios/) and the default behavior [for modally presented viewcontrollers](https://medium.com/@hacknicity/view-controller-presentation-changes-in-ios-13-ac8c901ebc4e).

I recommented checking out those WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/